# How to show an Alert via ajaxSubmit?

Tags: php, ajax

I'm trying to display an Alert message through ajaxSubmit as successful as in the example code below:

```
submitHandler: function( form ){ 
                var dados = $( form ).serialize(); 
                $.ajaxSubmit({  
                    type: "POST",   
                    url: "...",  
                    data: dados,  
                    complete: function( data )  
                    {  
                       // $("#cargo").resetForm();
                        alert("Alert Message"); 
                        $("#txtNome").focus();
                            $("#txtNome")
                            .hide()
                            .show("slow");
                            document.getElementById("cargo").reset();

                    } 
                }); 
                return false;  
            }
```

But every time the form data is saved, but no Alert message is shown! Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

check this code. It is working.

```
jQuery('#formId').validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
          jQuery("#formId").ajaxSubmit({
            success: function(data)     {
                             alert("hello");
                            jQuery('#element').html(data);
                        },
            data: {ajax:'true', tab:'true'}
        }); 
    }
});
```

Put your code in this format.

Comment: i have used alert on success callback function in code. So i want you to check it

Comment: I put this code in my project, and still not showing the Alert Message.

Comment: Check my answer.I have put the working code here and let me know.